# How to release memory managed by boost fast_pool_allocator?

Tags: c++, boost

I try to use boost::fast_pool_allocator on list to manage memory allocation.
Here is sample code I have,

```
    boost::fast_pool_allocator<int> alloc;
    std::list<int, boost::fast_pool_allocator<int>> data_pool(alloc);
    data_pool.push_back(1);
    data_pool.push_back(2);
    data_pool.clear();
    boost::singleton_pool<boost::fast_pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(int)>::purge_memory();
```

But the purge_memory never releases memory. I googled and see somebody mentioned sizeof(int) is not correct size for list node.

But how can I get correct list node size to make purge_memory works?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `singleton_pool::release_memory()` releases the allocated pool.